# I am getting OOM ARRAY SIZE EXCEEDS VM LIMIT when I run my pyspark job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a cluster of 10 workers each with 4CPUs and 16GB, executor memory 10 GB, and driver 10 GB.

about data:

the input data is a huge text file of size 1.5GB, inside the text file each record is separated by 1%% as a delimiter.

Each record is yet another file (each file may contain lines from 10 to 60000+) with a unique report id. the report_id should be extracted from the first line of the record.

And let's say record number 3 has a file of 1 GB.

when I try regexp_replace, I get the java array size exceeds the VM limit. I was trying to replace all the "\n" with "\r\n".

I have repartitioned the data to 30 partitions

Comment: 1. Show some code. 2. Add example of all the files you're talking about. Seems like you're talking about a file containing path of files to be processed, but it's pretty unclear. If you're trying to read a csv file then you can configure the delimiter like `spark.read.option("delimiter", "1%%").csv(path)`

Comment: well, the data inside the file is not in CSV file format but is in text. I have used spark text read. I can't share the contents though. Imagine if you have written three separate (separated by 1%%) essays or articles in a single file. And after the read, the data frame will have 3 rows. each essay occupies a row. I have to do string manipulation on all the essays in the row.

Comment: CSV doesn't really have to have `,` as delimiter/field-separator and `\n` as the line-separator, But I'm not sure if `1%%` can be used as a line-separator. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option for supported options. If that's not possible than (I think) you'll have to add another pre-step in your pipeline to break down the file into rows separated by an allowed separator.

Comment: 1%% is not the line separator, it is the file separator. let us say input.txt has content : 1%% report_id of the following file1\n content of file 1 (can have 100 lines) 1%% report_id of the following file2\n content of file 2 and so on. so when reading it using spark text reader using 1%% as separator. row 1 will contain file1 content row 2 will contain file 2 content.

Comment: see my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way around it, it is specific to my use case,
My input is not a collection of rows and columns separated by a comma or tab. My input contains 100 text files each file ends with 1%% marking the end of the file.

and simply put I just want to parse each file (100) and write out output for each file in txt format.

So my df contains one column named = value. row1 in the value column contains file1, row2 - file2 and so on.

the OOM error happened because the size of a particular file was over 1GB. So I created two jobs,

first job maps each file to each row and creates an index column and writes out the output as partition by index.

and the second job reads page by page instead of file from the partial output generated by the first job.